# Setup WebClient to use HttpComponents

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webclient, apache-httpcomponents

this works (i.e. default WebClient)

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(url);
Mono<String> mono = webClient.get().exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
Mono<String> monos = clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class);
     return monos;
     });
Mono<ServerResponse> response = ServerResponse.ok().body(mono, String.class);
```

and when replacing the first line with

```
HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpAsyncClientBuilder = HttpAsyncClients.custom();
    CloseableHttpAsyncClient closeableHttpAsyncClient = httpAsyncClientBuilder.build();
    ClientHttpConnector clientHttpConnector = new HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector(closeableHttpAsyncClient);
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(url).clientConnector(clientHttpConnector).build();
```

to use async HttpComponents.  This results in ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE with the client not sending the request to the server URL.
I couldn't find a minimally complete working example of the WebClient using HttpComponents setup.  What am I missing here?

The pom info - spring-boot-starter-parent 3.0.1, httpclient5 and httpcore5 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how did you tests the above code but here is a working test using `HttpAsyncClient`.

```
@Test
void test() {
    CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpAsyncClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom().build();
    ClientHttpConnector clientHttpConnector = new HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector(httpAsyncClient);
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("https://google.com")
            .clientConnector(clientHttpConnector)
            .build();

    Mono<String> request = webClient.get()
            .uri("/")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);

    StepVerifier.create(request)
            .assertNext(res -> log.info("response: {}", res))
            .verifyComplete();
}
```

Here are dependencies

`'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.1'`

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.2'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents.core5:httpcore5:5.2'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents.core5:httpcore5-reactive:5.2'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents.core5:httpcore5-h2:5.2'
```

Comment: As written, the above answer works for "http:" "google.com" but for "https:" "google.com" it returns "Invalid protocol version" 
I will accept the answer anyway and if someone can comment on "Invalid protocol version" error that would be helpful.

Comment: If you may see my test uses https and it works. Probably check your dependencies and it would be helpful if you add callstack

Comment: Yes.  Fixing the dependencies did the trick.